# Using graphql union return an array with some empty objects

Tags: graphql, union, apollo

I'm using graphql union - `union FolderOrFile = Folder | File`. When I query for only folders I get array containing folder objects with empty objects that are basically the file objects.

TypeDefs

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    union FolderOrFile = Folder | File
    type Folder {
        name: String
        path: String
        type: String
        children: [FolderOrFile]
    }
    type File {
        name: String
        path: String
        content: String
        type: String
        size: Int
        ext: String
        createdAt: String
    }
    type Query {
        folders: Folder
    }
`
```

Resolvers

```
const resolvers = {
    FolderOrFile: {
        __resolveType: obj => {
            if (obj.type === "file") {
                return 'File'
            }
            if (obj.type === "folder") {
                return 'Folder'
            }
        },
    },
    Query: {
        folders: async () => {
            const data = await folders
                .getFolder('./filesystem')
                .then(response => response)
            const appendData = await {
                name: 'Folder',
                path: './filesystem',
                type: 'folder',
                children: data,
            }
            return appendData
        }
    }
}
```

`folders` query

```
{
  folders {
    name
    path
    type
    children {
      ... on Folder {
        name
        path
        type
        children {
          ... on Folder {
            name
            path
            type
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response I get

```
{
  "data": {
    "folders": {
      "name": "Folder",
      "path": "./filesystem",
      "type": "folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Dishes",
          "path": "./filesystem/Dishes",
          "type": "folder",
          "children": [
            {},
            {},
            {
              "name": "Non Vegetarian",
              "path": "./filesystem/Dishes/Non Vegetarian",
              "type": "folder"
            },
            {
              "name": "Vegetarian",
              "path": "./filesystem/Dishes/Vegetarian",
              "type": "folder"
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The response shouldn't have those empty objects which in this case is for files being returned as empty object. Similarly when I query for file I get folders as empty objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify inline fragments for *all* the possible types when querying a field that returns a union or interface. In your query, you are only using an inline fragment for the `Folder` type. You're telling the server "if the returned object is a Folder, I want these fields". But if the object resolves to any other type, like File, you end up with an empty selection set because you have not specified which fields you want for that particular type.

```
{
  folders {
    name
    path
    type
    children {
      ... on Folder {
        name
        path
        type
      }
      ... on File {
        # whatever your File fields are
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This use case requires only the folders from this query, in another query I might only need File type and in another It might be both. Is that something that can't be done?

Comment: You can't use inline fragments as a means of filtering the response. GraphQL does not provide any built-in mechanism for filtering. Either add an argument to the `children` field and implement the filtering logic yourself, or expose two separate fields instead of children (`files` and `folders`).